# My natto got up to 47C for an hour

Tags: cultured-food

Should i just reduce the temperature to around 40 and keep going? Should I add some additional starter in case the culture was killed by the heat?

Answer (score 1):

The bacteria which ferment natto aren't particularly happy at 47 Celsius, but they certainly won't die. Reduce the temperature and continue as normal. There is no need to add additional starter.

Answer (score 1):

The bacteria in their vegetative state thrive in temperatures from 37-45°C. They can withstand temperatures up to 50°C before you need to start worrying about killing too many off. (Spores can withstand temperatures up to 100°C.) Even if you've killed some of the vegetative bacteria, they will quickly grow back, so there's no need to add additional starter. In general, when using bacteria for any kind of culture, you can start with less than what the recipe says, it may just take a little longer for the fermentation to progress to the same point.

So, in short, you are fine, and enjoy your natto!